# Flutter set icon using if condition

Tags: if-statement, flutter, dart

i want to  set the icon after an if condition , like if the condition is true i will set an icon else i will set another icon . my question is can i use it if statements in flutter widgets ? and if yes how can i use with the icon here  , here is my code  :

```
               if(this.iconName == 'green'){
                 Icon(Icons.verified_user, color: Colors.green),
               }else{
                 Icon(Icons.verified_user, color: Colors.blueAccent),
               }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try that

```
 Icon(Icons.verified_user: , color: this.iconName=='green'? Colors.green : Colors.blueAccent),
```